# PHP foreach loop to show particular items

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Ok, so I have loop which has 6 items (comments) as shown below.

- User1 Comment
- User2 Comment
- User1 Comment
- User1 Comment
- User3 Comment
- User4 Comment

If I put limit for 4 comment this is what I get

- User1 Comment
- User2 Comment
- User1 Comment
- User1 Comment

But instead of that I want to be able to eliminate same user comments and instead show others. It should look like that.

- User1 Comment
- User2 Comment
- User3 Comment
- User4 Comment

How can I achieve this ?

```
    foreach($latestcomments as $comment){

    echo $comment->content;

    }
```

Comment: do you want to show the most recent comment for each user?

Comment: Not possible with only one loop. You need at least two: one to find out what kind of comments you have and then one to output them.

Comment: @user20... if this is desired, not the loop is incorrect, but the way of fetching the data.

Comment: can you post your sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$shown = array();

foreach($latestcomments as $comment) {
  if(!isset($shown[$comment->user])) {
     $shown[$comment->user] = true;
     echo $comment->content;
  }
}
```

If the user hasn't been "shown" before, the comment will be shown. if they have, the comment will simply get skipped.

Comment: plus a $limit++ and $limit<=4

Answer (score 0):

Id do it like this...

```
$user = ""; $i=0;

foreach($latestcomments as $comment) {
 if($i<=4){
   if($comment->user!=$user){
    echo $comment->content;
    $user = $comment->user;
    $i++;} else { $user = $comment->user;}
 }
}
```